# (while, while not) multiply conditions //python loop

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Problem with a loop in Python. Below below there's a 'handwritten' code - which works and it works in a way it's supposed to work. I explain:

- `new[i]` is a list where each element is a time of a blink.
- `df2[' time'][i]` and `df2[' time'][i+1]` designate a time range for `new[i]`; if the time of `new[i]` is between those two `df2s...[i],[i+1]`, then `print(df2['letter'][i])` - else try with a higher index until you find the right range, then print a letter with that higher index.

Ok so it works. But when I try to write an algorithm using WHILE .. AND or WHILE NOT .. AND, (tried a few versions...) e.g.:

(this doesn't work:)

```py
for j in range(len(new)):
    while not new[j]>df2[' time'][i] and new[j]<df2[' time'][i+1]:
        i+1
    print(df2['letter'][i])
```

, which I understand as:

- for each element in list `new[]`, as long as this element isn't bigger than `df2[' time'][i]` and isn't smaller then time `df2[' time'][i+1]`, increase iteration by one, unless you found the right match, then print df2['letter'][i].

My problem is that `i` is always `1`, no matter what. Basically: what's wrong in my algorithm?

(this works:)

```py
if new[0]>df2[' time'][0] and new[0]<df2[' time'][1]:
    print(df2['letter'][0])
elif new[0]>df2[' time'][1] and new[0]<df2[' time'][2]:
    print(df2['letter'][1])
if new[1]>df2[' time'][2] and new[1]<df2[' time'][3]:
    print(df2['letter'][2])
elif new[1]>df2[' time'][3] and new[1]<df2[' time'][4]:
    print(df2['letter'][3])
if new[2]>df2[' time'][4] and new[2]<df2[' time'][5]:
    print(df2['letter'][4])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][5] and new[2]<df2[' time'][6]:
    print(df2['letter'][5])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][6] and new[2]<df2[' time'][7]:
    print(df2['letter'][6])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][7] and new[2]<df2[' time'][8]:
    print(df2['letter'][7])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][8] and new[2]<df2[' time'][9]:
    print(df2['letter'][8])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][9] and new[2]<df2[' time'][10]:
    print(df2['letter'][9])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][10] and new[2]<df2[' time'][11]:
    print(df2['letter'][10])
elif new[2]>df2[' time'][11] and new[2]<df2[' time'][12]:
    print(df2['letter'][11])
```

I tried `while not` loop with conjunction. Increase iteration by 1 seems not working.

for j in range(10):
while not new[j]>df2[' time'][i] and new[j]<df2[' time'][i+1]:
i=i+1
print(i)
print(df2['letter'][i],i,j)
j=j+1

Corrected i=i+1. Doesn't execute i=i+1 and print(i). Although j=j+1 works. WHILE NOT seems not caring about my conditions at all.

Comment: I want WHILE NOT to increase i index until the conditions are met. But i=i+1 seems not being executed. How to write it?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually updating i here. You need to state `i=i+1`

Comment: OP possibly meant `i+=1` and forgot the `=`

Comment: Hi. Yes I tried. You're both right, there should be i=i+1 or i+=1. Now it still doesn't work.

Comment: ```for j in range(10):
    while not new[j]>df2[' time'][i] and new[j]<df2[' time'][i+1]:
        i=i+1
        print(i)
    print(df2['letter'][i],i,j)
    j=j+1```    it shows: A 0 0
A 0 1
A 0 2
A 0 3
A 0 4
A 0 5
A 0 6
A 0 7
A 0 8
A 0 9

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to display this code with \n, when I push enter it only sends a comment.     Problem: i=i+1 doesn't work as well as print(i).

Comment: The for loop will naturally increment j at the end of the for loop so I don't see the reason for j+1

Comment: I see. What about while not loop? I want WHILE NOT to increase i index until the conditions are met.  But i=i+1 seems not being executed.